# How call subclass method by superclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have 2 subclass extended from the same superclass, and 3 objects will be created and store into an array of the superclass. I am wondering how can I call a subclass method by a superclass object, I try to convert the data type from Ship to CruiseShip or CargoShip but it does not work. If anyone can help I will be appreciated that.

Here is the superclass:

```
public class Ship {
   private String name;
   private String year;

   public Ship() {}
   public Ship(String n,String y) {...}
   public void setName() {...}
   public void setYear() {...}
   public void getName() {...}
   public void getYear() {...}
}
```

These two subclass basically are there same.

```
public class CruiseShip extends Ship {
   private int passenger;
   public CruiseShip() {}
   public CruiseShip() {...}
   public void setPassenager() {...}
   public int getPassenager() {...}
   public Strting showInfo() {this.getName()...etc}
}
```

```
public class CargoShip extends Ship {
   private int capacity;
   public CargoShip() {}
   public CargoShip() {...}
   public void setCapacity() {...}
   public int getCapacity() {...}
   public Strting showInfo() {this.getName()...etc}
}
```

Here is the main method:

```
public class report {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Ship[] shipList new Ship[3];
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {//using for loop to create 3 objects randomly and pass into array}
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
         if (shipList[i] instanceof CruiseShip) {
            ((CruiseShip)shipList[i]).showInfo();  //This way is not work.
         }
         else {
            ((CargoShip)shipList[i]).showInfo();  //This way is not work.
         }
```

Comment: You should probably have an abstract method `showInfo()` on `Ship`.

Comment: @user15793316 the program has no response and exit when the first for loop is complete. And sorry about the `i=o`;`I<3` mistake

Comment: I think that you should google "Liskov substitution principle". This applies to your situation.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I think I find the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Polymorphisms and Late Bindig. Basically late binding says that the appropriate method to be executed is determined at runtime based on the actual type of the object. So

```
class Ship {
  public String showInfo() {return "I'm a ship";}
}

class CruiseShip extends Ship {
  public String showInfo() {return "I'm a cruiseShip";}
}

class CargoShip extends Ship {
  public String showInfo() {return "I'm a cargoShip";}
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
     Ship[] ships = new Ship[]{new Ship(), new CargoShip(), new CruiseShip()};
     for (Ship ship: ships) {
        System.out.println(ship.showInfo());
        // I'm a ship
        // I'm a cargoShip
        // I'm a cruiseShip
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the question you are trying to ask,
but this may answer the question you did ask.

```
public abstract class Ship
{
    public final boolean hoot()
    {
        return implementHoot();
    }
    
    protected abstract boolean implementHoot();
}

public class BlamShip
extends Ship
{
    protected boolean implementHoot()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

Subclass methods (overrides) are automatically called even if the reference is of type super-class.  You don't have to do anything.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I answered the question he actually asked.    It appears that he is asking "if a subclass has the same method as the super, then how does the subclass's method get called.   As another person answered, polymorphism takes care of the problem and it automatically gets called.